# multiple definition of `malloc'

Tags: compiler-errors, linker-errors

I am compiling a program, which is a single file. It uses a library called HPX and that in turn uses jemalloc.

The problem is that I am getting multiple definition error due to it needing jemalloc, and the linker conflicting with the system provided malloc.

Any help?

I am using the following command to compile:

`cc -std=gnu99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L -I/path/installs/hpx-4.0.0/include  -g -O2 -o ./bin/a.out main.c -lm -L/path/installs/hpx-4.0.0/lib -lhpx -lrt -lffi -lstdc++ -lpciaccess -lcityhash -lurcu-qsbr -lurcu-cds -ljemalloc`

Error:

/usr/lib/../lib64/libc.a(malloc.o): In function `__libc_malloc':

/usr/src/packages/BUILD/glibc-2.11.3/malloc/malloc.c:3617: multiple definition of `malloc'

/path/installs/hpx-4.0.0/lib/libjemalloc.a(jemalloc.o):/tmp/hpx-4.0.0/hpx/contrib/jemalloc/src/jemalloc.c:1550: first defined here

Comment: Have you tried moving -ljemalloc earlier in the chain?

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this thread](https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/issues/442)? It might help.

Comment: Could you please share the source code?